# How to compare and sort items in a TreeSet?

Tags: java, sorting

I have a class called Player with a wins and losses.

```
public class Player
{
    private String          name ; 
    private int             ranking=0; 
    private int             wins = 0 ;
    private int             lossess = 0 ; 


    private boolean         isPrivate =false; 
    private int             experiance =0; 

public float getWinRatio()
{ 
     if( getExperiance() <= 0 )  return -0.0f ;  
     return  (getWins()/(float)getExperiance()) ;         
}
```

I have a TreeSet with 10000 Player objects. How would I compare them to each other and then sort them based on this win ratio function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your methods in your class properly for it to compile.  But once you do that, you can pass a `Comparator` to the `TreeSet` like this.

```java
  Set<Player> players = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Player::getWinRatio));
```

Here I just add the values to the TreeSet.

```
      int[] numbs = { 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 9, 7, 6, 8
      };

      // Integer has a natural ordering in ascending order so no
      // Comparator was needed 
      Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
      for (int n : numbs) {
         set.add(n);
      }
```

Voila!  They are sorted.

```
      System.out.println(set);
```

If want to sort them in reversed order, you can allocate the TreeSet like this.

```
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

For your win ration sort, you can reverse the order like this.

```
 Set<Player> players =
            new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Player::getWinRatio).reversed());
```

Comment: Please elaborate. I did that. Then what does the for loop/for each loop look like to compare the players against each other?

Comment: The `TreeSet` will sort items automatically by their natural relationship to each other.   It could be names, numbers, etc.  You didn't implement the `Comparable` interface in your class but you can provide one when you create the `TreeSet` by passing a `Comparator`.  It simply sorts all the items as they are added based on the win ratio.

Comment: You don't need a loop.  The `TreeSet` does it for you as you add items. I'll post an example.

Comment: Okay thanks. So lets say I had a method that looped through everything and compared them to each other with nested for loops. That method can now be completely deleted and the items will be sorted. Correct?

Comment: Correct!  Just try it with a TreeSet.  That's what treesets do.  They maintain a sorted order based on how you want to sort them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `TreeSet` with `Comparator` which compares players based on the `winRatio`. Then, you just need to copy the players from your original `TreeSet` to the new `TreeSet`. Given below is the reference code:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.TreeSet;

class Player {
    private String name;
    private int ranking = 0;
    private int wins = 0;
    private int lossess = 0;
    private boolean isPrivate = false;
    private int experiance = 0;

    public Player(String name, int ranking, int wins, int lossess, boolean isPrivate, int experiance) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.ranking = ranking;
        this.wins = wins;
        this.lossess = lossess;
        this.isPrivate = isPrivate;
        this.experiance = experiance;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getExperiance() {
        return experiance;
    }

    public int getWins() {
        return wins;
    }

    public float getWinRatio() {
        if (getExperiance() <= 0)
            return -0.0f;
        return (getWins() / (float) getExperiance());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player [name=" + name + ", ranking=" + ranking + ", wins=" + wins + ", lossess=" + lossess
                + ", isPrivate=" + isPrivate + ", experiance=" + experiance + "]";
    }
}

class DefaultComparator implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}

class PlayerWinRatioComparator implements Comparator<Player> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2) {
        return p1.getWinRatio() > p2.getWinRatio() ? 1 : (p1.getWinRatio() == p2.getWinRatio() ? 0 : -1);
    }
}

public class TreeSetExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Player> original = new TreeSet<Player>(new DefaultComparator());
        original.add(new Player("A", 5, 1, 2, true, 4));
        original.add(new Player("B", 4, 2, 1, false, 5));
        original.add(new Player("C", 2, 3, 2, true, 3));
        original.add(new Player("X", 3, 2, 3, false, 2));
        original.add(new Player("Y", 6, 4, 2, true, 1));
        original.add(new Player("Z", 1, 2, 4, true, 6));

        TreeSet<Player> copy = new TreeSet<Player>(new PlayerWinRatioComparator());

        // Copy the elements of original TreeSet to the copy TreeSet
        for (Player player : original) {
            copy.add(player);
        }

        //Display the elements copy TreeSet
        for (Player player : copy) {
            System.out.println(player);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Player [name=A, ranking=5, wins=1, lossess=2, isPrivate=true, experiance=4]
Player [name=Z, ranking=1, wins=2, lossess=4, isPrivate=true, experiance=6]
Player [name=B, ranking=4, wins=2, lossess=1, isPrivate=false, experiance=5]
Player [name=C, ranking=2, wins=3, lossess=2, isPrivate=true, experiance=3]
Player [name=Y, ranking=6, wins=4, lossess=2, isPrivate=true, experiance=1]
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes me understand how to do it!